# How to reference a ListView Item from a PopupMenu on that item

Tags: android

I have a custom adapter for a list view that is in a fragment. Each item in the list view has a popup menu. Options on the popup menu are to move items in the list view up or down. My problem is how to reference the listview from within the popup menu item click listener.

The adapter->getView and popup listener code is:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_media_morebtn, null);
    parent.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

    final ImageButton imgCk = convertView.findViewById(R.id.moreButton);

    imgCk.setImageResource(R.drawable.more_hor);
    imgCk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            v.findViewById(R.id.moreButton).setTag(position);
            showPopupMenu(v, position);

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private void showPopupMenu(View view, int position) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view, Gravity.END);

    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mediapopup, popup.getMenu());

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.movedown:
                    //move item down

                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to acheive when movedown is clicked? I mean include your code.

Comment: I haven't done the code for that yet. It will need to move the listview item at 'position' down 1 place in the listview. I just can't work out how to reference the listview from in here.

Comment: You need to figure out how to do it first. Search here for that

Comment: I would like to think this is similar to RV.  My code inside onMenuItemClick: if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_clear_playlist) {

           if (playlist instanceof SmartPlaylist) {
            ClearSmartPlaylistDialog.create((SmartPlaylist) playlist).show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "CLEAR_SMART_PLAYLIST_" + playlist.getPlaylistTitle());
            return true;
           }
          }

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to reference the views inside the PopUp. PopUp is an overlay, i.e, it has it's own view structure that is dependent of the Activity/Fragment you're in. And each item in the list is references in MenuItem, not like you'd reference Views